# The video game in the movie The Dirt Bike Kid

Tags: identify-this-game

At minute 25 of the movie [The Dirt Bike Kid](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090948/) (1985) there is a scene: a man playing a video game.

[image]

The video game is similar to *Space Invaders* but is not *Space Invaders*.

Anyone recognize the game?

Comment: I'm flagging this question because [that man is playing Galaga](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4Fy6AUMv8E).

Comment: Not exactly a retrocomputing, probably better suited in Arqade https://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it makes me feel so old that this is a serious question 

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The game is [Galaga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaga), by Midway.

Comment: Galaga is one of the most popular arcade games of all time.  Along with pac-man and space invaders, it's one of the few retro arcade games that you still see in arcades today.  It's really surprising to come across someone who has never seen it.

Comment: @user4574 Ten more years and the generation after the zoomers won't recognize Space Invaders either.  Time in its aging course obscures all things.

Comment: @user4574 Every day, someone is one of today's lucky [ten thousand](https://xkcd.com/1053/).

Comment: @user4574 According to Google Trends Galaga is *by far* the most popular in the US and Canada. In the US the relative popularity breakdown is 63% pacman, 22% galaga and 15% space invaders. For comparison in the UK it is 48% pacman, 6% galaga and 46% space invaders.